# Unable to turn on WiFi on Nokia Lumia 925

Tags: lumia, wifi, lumia-925

I've been running Windows Phone 8.1 Developer Preview on a Nokia Lumia 925 for the past few weeks and everything has been fine. I come into work this morning and I notice that the WiFi is off. I tried to switch it on but I'm immediately presented with an error message: "Can't do this at the moment", e.g.:

[image]

To try to fix this I've restarted the phone, done soft & hard resets, updated everything that needed updating, and restored to factory settings. Nothing is working, and this error message doesn't give me any information.

What could be causing this and how can I fix it?

To be clear, this is not an issue with connecting to a router, this problem lies in turning on the phone's WiFi module. Also, Internet Sharing is turned off.

Comment: The only time I've really seen that is when internet sharing was turned on

Comment: I checked and Internet Sharing is turned off.

Comment: Try turning on internet sharing, using it and then turning it back off ?

Comment: Try asking Cortana to turn off WiFi

Answer (score 1):

If hard resets won't work I think your only option is to repair your device using the Nokia Software Recovery Tool.

Comment: It's a company phone so they just got me a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade your Nokia Lumia from Windows Phone 8.1 Preview and and get the official update to resolve this issue..

Comment: thanks, but I've long since dumped the Windows Phone and went back to Android.